# Is there a way to add Swagger2 to a SpringBoot Application with Gradle and hateoas?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have an existing application that needs hateoas dependency and I'm trying to add Swagger2. 
No matter what version I try whenever I try to add the @EnableSwagger2 annotation or @EnableSwagger2MVC annotation it is not picked up. I've tried adding @Import({springfox.documentation.spring.data.rest.configuration.SpringDataRestConfiguration.class}) but it's just not getting picked up.

I can see that the Swingfox dependcies have been imported but the annotations will not be picked up

Current build.gradle file is set up like so;

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2')
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2')
}
```

I've also tried the plugin and other versions like version 3 snapshot and 2.4.0.

Any help greatly appreciated as it has me baffled. Surely it's supported?

Comment: yes you can do that

Comment: Greate, now any idea how?